# Adjusting distance between plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I have a couple of ggplot plots that I want to merge using `grid.arrange()`

When I merge the plots there's a large white area around each plot making them far away from each other.

Is there a way to adjust the distance between the plots? and the size of the white area around the plots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `theme(plot.margin)` function in ggplot2 to reduce the spacing.

A simple working example here :

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

x <- seq(1,10,1)
y <- dnorm(x,mean=10,sd=0.5)


 # Create p1
p1 <- qplot(x,y) + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,-0.5,1),"cm"))

# Create p2
p2 <- qplot(x,y) + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(-0.5,1,1,1),"cm"))

grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

**Edit**
The four numbers are `c(bottom,left,top,right)`

Sample output

[image]

Comment: can you explain what the 4 numbers within unit() are referring to?

Comment: Edited my answer to refer to four numbers.